# How can I create a background pattern with small, cartoon-like, hand-drawn stencil images?

Tags: background, patterns

For example, in this picture (ignore the logo):

[image]

I love how the **background** is cute and made up of small, simple images. Where can I find resources like this background, or how can I recreate it?

Answer (score 3):

I had misread the original question, and Matt's extensive answer covers the 'finding resources' part of it perfectly. But in case you want to re-create the background pattern yourself, you can do it quite easily using probably any graphic software.

The steps would be something like this:

[image]

- Create a square canvas / artwork for the background color
- Add your drawings (you can use vectors, PNG images with transparency, shapes, etc)
- Make the drawings semi-transparent (these are 20% alpha)
- Making sure the design is [seamless](http://creaturecomfortsblog.com/home/2012/04/17/creating-seamless-patterns-with-photoshop.html), and convert it into a pattern (in Photoshop, this can be done via `Edit > Define Pattern`.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try Google and search for "vector patterns", "vector pattern backgrounds", or "vector pattern maker".  A few sites that come to mind if you are looking for vector backgrounds:

- [VectorStock](http://www.vectorstock.com/)
- [DinPattern](http://www.dinpattern.com/)
- [SquidFingers](http://www.squidfingers.com/patterns/)
- [Pattern8](http://pattern8.com/)
- [DreamsTime](http://www.dreamstime.com/search.php?srh_field=pattern&firstvalue=pattern&lastsearchvalue=Vector%20Floral%20Pattern%20seamless&s_ph=y&s_il=y&s_sm=all&s_st=new&memso=y&s_cf=0&s_catid=&s_cliid=&s_colid=&memorize_search=1&s_exc=&s_excp=&s_sp=&s_sl1=y&s_sl2=y&s_sl3=y&s_sl4=y&s_sl5=y&s_color1=FFFFFF&s_percent1=10&s_color2=FFFFFF&s_percent2=10&s_rsf=0&s_rst=7&s_clc=y&s_clm=y&s_orp=y&s_ors=y&s_orl=y&s_orw=y)
- [Alice Grafixx](http://alice-grafixx.de/patterns)
- [ColorLouvers](http://www.colourlovers.com/pattern/templates)
- [TileMachine](http://www.tilemachine.com/gallery/)
- [Citrus Moon Patterns](http://citrusmoon.typepad.com/patterns/)