# How can i make a poster background like this in Adobe AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background

[image]

Especially the chalk-like stroked food icons

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a background pattern with small, cartoon-like, hand-drawn stencil images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21319/how-can-i-create-a-background-pattern-with-small-cartoon-like-hand-drawn-stenc) or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57287/how-do-i-scatter-icons-all-over-a-background-randomly

Comment: Yes yes! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

well for me, when you have chosen ur size, create the vector art background you want to use. so if it is a group of icons or vector art you want to create them and put them together. you can get vector art from freepik.com

i will advice drawing a rectangle over the artboard shape, add the preferred color and then lock the rectangle, so it doesnt move.

for the art u what to use as the background group them together and make a copy and then merge that copy to form 1 design.

place it over the rectangle and then go to properties and reduce the opacity to prefered level.

i believe that should get you started